# How can I change top level package name in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

I have a package structure: com.report.domain.model

I would like to change it to com.reporting.domain.model. When I select *Refactor* → *Rename* on package com.report.domain.model, I only see an option to rename 'model'. I have tried switching between *Project* view and *Package*, but to no avail. I know how to make this change in Eclipse via Navigator view, but how can I do the same in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

In the `Project` Window, click on the Gears icon in the title bar [image: Gears icon] and deselect "Compact Empty Middle Packages". Then you can separately select the `report` package and rename it.

See also: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project-tool-window.html#d242351e401

N.B. As of IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3, there is a bug in the menu and when the option is selected, it has a different label "**Hide** Empty Middle Packages", see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168362.

Answer (score 59):

### To change the full package name:

[User jkovacs has already answered this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764277/how-can-i-change-top-level-package-name-in-intellij-idea/16764347#16764347), but I'm going to cover this in a bit more detail. For example, if you want to change `com.example.app` to `my.awesome.game`, then:

1. In your ***Project pane***, click on the little gear icon ([image: Gears icon])
2. Uncheck / de-select the `Compact Empty Middle Packages` option:

   [image: Compact Empty Middle Packages]
3. Your package directory will now be broken up in individual directories.
4. Individually select each directory you want to rename, and:

   - Right-click it
   - Select `Refactor`
   - Click on `Rename`
   - In the Pop-up dialog, click on `Rename Package` instead of Rename Directory
   - Enter the new name and hit **Refactor**
   - Allow a minute to let Android Studio update all changes
   - *Note: When renaming `com` in Android Studio, it might give a warning. In such case, select* **Rename All**:

     [image]
5. Now open your ***Gradle Build File*** (`build.gradle` - Usually `app` or `mobile`). Update the `applicationId` to your new Package Name and Sync Gradle, if it hasn't already been updated automatically:

   [image: Refactor Directories]
6. ***Done!*** Anyway, Android Studio needs to make this process a little simpler.

Comment: You're definitely right it needs to be made simpler. 4 years later and still waiting... I did a three-level package rename today (let's call it A.B.C to D.E.F) and I found that (a) references to the class "R" were not updated, (b) some references in XML files were changed to be like "D.B.C.A.B.C", lots of things to update manually. I guess as people don't do this very often, they don't want to put much effort into making it smoother.

Comment: Actually I don't think it's correct to select "rename all". I have a project with multiple modules, I was trying to rename "com" in just one of the modules (e.g. module 1 has com.foo, module 2 has com.bar, I want to change module 1 to org.baz, without affecting module 2). When I selected "rename all", all of the com packages were renamed, not only the ones in the module I clicked to refactor. When I did it again and selected "rename current", it worked properly.