# Rename package in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

How do you rename packages in the new IDE Android Studio, based on IntelliJ IDEA?

Is there an automatic refactoring included?

I want to make bulk refactoring, but I don't know how. I worked two years with Eclipse and in Eclipse it's a one-click operation.

Comment: Please see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27232067/513450). I have successfully managed to rename my project using the steps I have described.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change project name on Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio)

Comment: Step by Step Process for Changing Package name...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46945668/6915572

Comment: The answer by Sheharyar works as expected. i.e 1. Refactor 2. Edit build.gradle. However, you will have to follow it up by changing the app_name attribute in strings.xml file too!

Answer (score 3523, accepted):

### In Android Studio, you can do this:

For example, if you want to change `com.example.app` to `my.awesome.game`, then:

1. In your ***Project panel***, click on the little gear icon ( [image: Gears icon] )
2. Uncheck the `Compact Empty Middle Packages` option

   [image: Compact Empty Middle Packages]
3. Your package directory will now be broken down into individual directories
4. Individually select each directory you want to rename, and:

- Right-click on it
- Select `Refactor`
- Click on `Rename`
- In the pop-up dialog, click on `Rename Package` instead of Rename Directory
- Enter the new name and hit **Refactor**
- Click **Do Refactor** in the bottom
- Allow a minute to let Android Studio update all changes
- *Note: When renaming `com` in Android Studio, it might give a warning. In such case, select* **Rename All**

  [image]

5. Now open your ***Gradle Build File*** (`build.gradle` - Usually `app` or `mobile`). Update the `applicationId` in the `defaultConfig` to your new Package Name and Sync Gradle, if it hasn't already been updated automatically:

   [image: Refactor Directories]
6. You may need to change the `package=` attribute in your manifest.
7. Clean and Rebuild.

   [image: Clean and Rebuild]
8. ***Done!*** Anyway, Android Studio needs to make this process a little simpler.

Comment: I have refactored once and then followed the step 5 and worked for me.

Comment: Please note if you're following above method and Google Play still keeps insisting that the package has 'com.example' in it then you need to change the applicationId in your build.gradle

Comment: build.config and R files are not getting gererated after doing this.

Comment: this procedure is much more ugly on Eclipse... :/

Comment: WARNING: if you select "Rename all" when renaming also "com" it will rename not only things into the selected module but into all modules into this project

Comment: This is NOT AS BAD AS IT LOOKS!! It's a beautifully-documented procedure that WORKS!!  I had 371 references to old package, including 1 in BuildConfig.java, WHICH IT SAYS NOT TO EDIT, so I didn't and all was OK when I created the new APK file and uploaded it to Google Play Store. You DO have to change the `build.gradle` file that contains `APPLICATION_ID`. **GREAT SOLUTION!!**  I LOVE the comment above saying this is much more ugly in Eclipse! I don't know if that's accurate (I don't use Eclipse), but I hope Android Studio is indeed better at package rename than most posters believe.

Comment: Step 5 is really what i was missing

Comment: JUST FOR THE INFORMATION: Android studio lets you set the Package name as capital letters as well but then gives an error of Malformed Android Manifest. So Package name must be in small letters.

Comment: What should I do if I need to delete part of the package? I mean, from `com.example.test` to `com.example`

Comment: @Antonio drag the files in `com.example.test` to `com.example` and then delete `com.example.test`.

Comment: This procedure worked for me. I had to also change the AndroidManifest.xml to reflect the new name. For example -> package="my.awesome.game" >

Comment: Works well so upvoted, but some entries in the manifest were not updated, specifically those relating to <receiver><intent-filter>

Comment: Fun Fact:  If, in your imports, you use a wildcard

`com.example.app.teeth.*`

AS will not automatically rename it using the new project name.  But, a simple attempt to build will show you all the warnings

Comment: Better than other suggestions, still had to edit imports in many files. Seems like such a common need - Google really should make a wizard to do it right for such a common need.

Comment: what a great answer...super @Sheharyar.. it is working for AS1.1.0 also

Comment: I'd like to add that in AS +2.0 it prompts for "only directory" / "package" options, choose Package and it will do "the magic" for ourselves. Otherwise it will only change one directory name.

Comment: After I did according to your answer, I ended up to replace all the R imports to the new one. Android Studio didn't do that for me. So in all my files where #import x.y.z.R; was defined, I replaced it with #import a.b.c.R; After that it worked.

Comment: It is not working in Android studio 2.1. Android studio just silently refuses to rename anything.

Comment: Step 2 is important :)

Comment: @Vlado - did you actually click on "Refactor" once Android Studio searches for the usages? I missed this step...easy to miss

Comment: Thanks for that solution, I still must to replace package manual from some file in build folder, build immediately folder, and I must delete test folder for run no error :\

Comment: If you are not using gradle, update package name in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Also you might need to delete .gradle folder in the main directory and then "sync project with gradle"  from IDE.

Comment: NOTE: This will NOT refactor AIDL files.  (as of Android Studio 2.2) (and probably won't for a while). But otherwise, This was great. Also I'm not sure how you 'delete'/'add' a new package part in the middle... other than deleting/adding to end and then renaming all the packages that need it.

Comment: Seriously, if you're in Seattle sometime, lunch is on me. This was driving me freaking crazy!

Comment: I think the reason the process isn't simple is that it isn't recommended to rename your packages once the application is on Play Store.

Comment: Another note for this method: if your project is very large, Android Studio will freeze up in the process.

Comment: Really awesome, thank you. Had problems with the R class afterward; needed to make manual package changes in the manifest.

Comment: If you are using firebase, change your package_name in google-services.json as well.

Comment: What if I want to change `com.example.new.app` to `com.example.app`.

Comment: I still don't understand why we need to de-select `Compact Empty Middle Packages` to do this. **Is this an AS bug?** Surely sound like it, since selecting the whole name (in various ways), only changes the tail of the package name.

Comment: **This method still fails to refactor any AIDL files** you may have. These need to be changed manually with Search and Replace.

Comment: It worked and in later android studio versions,package name is refactored in gradle and manifest files automatically!

Comment: I've just done this and it does not work (In Windows, Android Studio doesn't recognise the change and Clean All/ Rebuild doesn't do it nor does `refresh`), I would recommend 1) closing android studio .. 2) navigating the the app dir manually rename the folders in `.\src\main\java` then 3) use `notepad++` to do a global find and replace on the string `before.androidwork.com` to `after.changed.net` in the `.\src\main\java` dir

Comment: Getting this Error `Error:org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing` Please help

Comment: Why not select whole package name com.example.tutorial -> Then Right Click -> Refractor -> Rename (input ->tutorial1) OR Refractor -> Move (input -> com1.example1). Only might need to update package name in gradle file then. * Need to select whole package name.

Comment: In the current version of Android Studio, this doesn't work in all cases. I just tried to change the "top-level domain" (as in `cc.example.www`) from `cc` to `com`. When renaming (step 4 in this answer), I got the error "Cannot create file '.../build/generated/source/r/release/com'. File already exists." The `com` directory does already exist, because I was using it for some other packages (third-party libraries). I haven't looked yet to see whether this bug is in the issue tracker.

Comment: I have multi-modular project and I just want to refactor one module. I can change the scope of the usage but it only then shows me the usage and I can't refactor one module. Is there a way to do that somehow?

Comment: You made my day buddy because of you iam publishing my first app

Comment: In My case, it was Hide Empty Middle Packages in the 1st step, Thanks buddy

Comment: It doesn't refactor everything in your code. You still have to do some dirty work.

Comment: This ALMOST worked, but for some reason, I get errors in my app>source>androidTest directory.  In "ExampleInstrumentedTest" I could not import:import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;  and I received a "cannot resolve symbol" error.  Any idea why?

Comment: My question is: what to do if you want to remove a layer of package name: from com.example.app to example.app? I am stuck at step 4.

Comment: I do not see a "DO Refactor" anywhere

Comment: i renamed the com directory and it takes ages.. hmmm

Comment: How can you refactor, if your actual package is level1.level2.level3.leve4 and i want to set levelx.levely.levelz, there difference of levels, only 3, before 4, thanks!

Comment: If you're using any external services, check any key restrictions that might be tied to the previous package name.  I got caught out with that on Google Maps, for example, which gave me a blank map after I'd changed the package name.  I just had to change the key restrictions to have the new package name on the Google Console.

Comment: be careful! If you use google analytic json, then change package name that used in that json file.

Comment: An answer you wrote six years ago just put a smile on my face. Thank you. By the way, is there a better way to do this now?

Comment: I suggest also to click on `File` and click to `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` to be sure that everything has been cleaned.

Comment: **The Gear Icon changed!**
It looks like **`⁝`** now

Comment: I don't think this works with the latest version of Android Studio, at least it didn't work for me.

Comment: Do not forget to change your **AndroidManifest.xml**

Comment: 7) don't forget in `AndroidManifest.xml` to change the package name. It saved me a lot of time.

Comment: This will also help in addition to this accepted answer : https://johncodeos.com/how-to-change-your-project-name-package-name-in-android-studio/

Comment: I followed this procedure now in March 2020 and am amazed to see, the test packages were also refactored and the manifest file was also refactored with the correct package name after doing the step no. 4. Well done Android Studio.

Comment: If you are using Jetpack Navigation, you'll need to rename the argument types.

Comment: Worked fine, thanks! In the newer IntelliJ versions, there is no settings wheel icon. Instead, we can right click on the project exploer pane.

Comment: This gave me an error in the first attempt. I restarted android studio, then all worked fine.

Comment: When I did this, I had to fix all of my imports of my own code, meaning, for example, there where a lot of `import org.example` that had to be changed to `import com.example`.

Comment: please choose Edit -> Find -> Replace in path (Ctrl + Shift + R) and then find com.example.oldpackagename and replace with ..newpakcagename. This is not done otherwise. thanks

Comment: Paragraph 2 renamed to:
2. Uncheck the "Compact Middle Packages" option

Comment: It's 2021, and it's quite a painful process.

Comment: GRADLE : go to setting.gradle file and also change the rootProject.name = "oldname"

Comment: Am getting `Unresolved reference: R` after renaming the package.

Comment: its only on similar domain , not work like a charm if old ( ```com.example.app``` ) change into ( ```com.br.example.app``` )

Comment: It's not working with "Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3". When I want to rename the package from "com.hello.demo" to "my.cool.game", it comes out with "com.hello.my.cool.game".

Comment: The UI in Android Studio has changed over the years. For example, currently (in Dolphin) there is a "Tree Appearance" menu item and "Compact Middle Packages" is on its submenu.

Comment: Maybe add another step, I did all this and there was one more thing wrong: When I renamed the package in my project, it somehow also edited my Run/Debug Configurations. Make sure Launch under the Launch Options section is not set to None. Usually, this should be Default Activity.

Comment: 2023 and this does not work anymore. The .R import is never built under the new package.

Comment: it's workable for me

Comment: **TO RESOLVE** `Unresolved reference: R` - **delete .idea and .gradle folder** in project and then do `Rebuild Project`. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 640):

Another good method is: First create a new package with the desired name by right clicking on the Java folder → *New* → *Package*.

Then, select and drag all your classes to the new package. Android Studio will refactor the package name everywhere.

Finally, delete the old package.

Done.

**Very important:**

*You have to manually change **AndroidManifest.xml** and **build.gradle** file to the new package if you use this method.*

Comment: You may need to update your Android Manifest file to reference the new package if you use this method. Very simple step though, great solution.

Comment: You might have to restart Android studio to update the .idea/workspace.xml

Comment: You also may need to change your build.gradle to reflect the new package

Comment: This works, but when I restart, under Recent Projects, it is still listed by name as the old name even though ti points to, opens and runs as the new duplicated version.  How do you change the way it is listed in Recent Projects?

Comment: Thank you, this worked. So embarrassing that Android Studio can't do a simple Refactor -> Rename.

Comment: when he says to make a new package, I found that if you add the new folder in the right place using explorer, and then move in the folders it works fine. I was impressed!! This is Magic.

Comment: good method but had to do 2 more things(other than updating manifest file) to make it completely work, firstly had to change/rename the R file imports in whole project and  secondly appdebug was using old package name( visible in run window of studio) added applicationId  "com.packagename" in app build.gradle defaultconfig ..

Comment: besides what @baboo did, in the build.gradle file I changed the applicationdId to reflect my updated package name.

Comment: @baboo To make that first part easier, you can optimize file imports for the whole project by pressing Ctrl+Alt+O and selecting all files, then clicking run.  This is especially useful if you have many activities and other classes with R file imports.

Comment: This is great, just needed to also update manifest and then Build -> Clean Project

Comment: @user462990 what about the test package how to refractor that using your method

Comment: After doing this simply find and replace your old package name with new in code directory and change applicationid inside build.grandle and you are done.

Comment: not the best choose for a big project where you have many packages and classes, you'll have to re import all of them

Comment: Getting this Error Error:org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing Please help

Comment: If you referenced to a custom class in xml, you need to change that to.

Comment: This works for me because accepted answer explain only rename, not explaining adding new folder in between

Comment: Beware. This method doesn't refactor the package declared inside Kotlin files.

Comment: This reduced effort.Nice solution.

Comment: I am using Android Studio, and this worked for me.  A couple caveats:  (1) If you are using Subversion, then make sure to commit any changes in your work-space, and do a Subversion update of your work-space before starting this process.  (2) My project is mixed Java/Kotlin.  After I did this it seemed that I still had a lot of import statements that still referred to the old package name (which no longer existed and so caused compiler errors).  I just did a global find/replace of those old package references (right-click on the Project Node in Android Studio and select "Replace in path...").

Comment: I have to manually change R import in every activity and some static field imports are also need to be changed

Comment: adding to @baboo comment, we can directly rename  the R file imports in the whole project by pressing ctrl+shift+R by selecting the package name at any one class

Answer (score 242):

Changing the **application ID** (which is now independent of the package name) can be done very easily in one step.
You don't have to touch AndroidManifest.
Instead do the following:

1. right click on the root folder of your project.
2. Click "Open Module Setting".
3. Go to the Flavours tab (It might also be called Default Config in the newer versions).
4. Change the applicationID to whatever package name you want. Press OK.

Note this will *not* change the package name. The decoupling of Package Name and Application ID is explained here:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Comment: This only changes the name in gradle, and nowhere else.

Comment: @Jacob R. That's all that matters. The package name in gradle trumps other names.

Comment: This is one holy grail answer! Very Smart!

Comment: This needs to be chosen as a correct answer since it is very simple and fast way to follow.

Comment: This needs to be accepted, other answer are lengthy and you can't change `com.example.sample` to `com.example` using other answers

Comment: It didn't change the package ID in my manifest file... Hmmmm Something I  am missing here?

Comment: UPDATE:

This is working but how about the package in the manifest file? Is not used by Android studio?

Comment: @mboy the name in gradle only matters, because it trumps the name in manifest.

Comment: @hwat  after I change the package name using this method everything works great except `context.getPackageName()` .. It cannot identify the updated package name.. Any hint?

EDIT:

Found the answer here - http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Comment: Still requires every file in the project and Manifest to be manually updated. What a pain.

Comment: @Frank You don't need to do that. Read my comment above to Jacob.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Worked like charm with minimum time

Comment: this is the most effective and fastest way

Comment: Wish it worked, no directories changed and nothing updated in any files I could find. Yes, it does build. Seems like there is no solution to easily change "com.foo1.foo2.foo3"  "com.newname". Refactor doesn't handle this case either.  Looks like it's better do directory changes and then a search and replace outside of Android Studio. Eclipse was so much easier.

Comment: @Frank Please refer to my comment to Jacob. This changes the name in gradle which trumps other names in other files.

Comment: library cannot change their applicationId this way.

Comment: It does change the package name, but then the app crashes with this error message `unable to resolve virtual method 8734: Ljava/util/Locale;.toLanguageTag ()Ljava/lang/String;` Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This is simple and to the point.  I needed to upload to playstore, and this is the way to distinguish apps, i.e. free, pro etc... More here:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html

Comment: This is the BEST suggestion so far. I am faced with an issue that I have to update my old app with different packaging name, and all I need is to change application ID! Amazing tip, and thanks!

Comment: I have to join the choir here praising this answer. I'm changing my free game app to a .99 app, and this was so much simpler than messing with refactoring, which has never completely worked with my complex project. Only issue was having to replace the json file with a newly created one for Firebase database. This doesn't change the application ID there, which is to be expected. You'll get a can't find application ID error until you do this if you use Firebase.

Comment: If you are trying to change your package name to upload into playstore this is for you.

Comment: How is this done in 2022? or projects without flavours.

Comment: "Flavours" seems to have been renamed to "Default Config"

Answer (score 109):

The approach used by me for renaming the package name is as follows:-

**Step 1**
: Select the Project option from the left menu of Android Studio

[image]

**Step 2**
: Right-click on java and add a new package and set the desired package name

[image]

**Step 3**
: Enter your new package name

[image]

**Step 4**
:Copy all the files from your old package and paste into the new package

[image]

**Step 5**
:Rename the package name in the manifest file

[image]

**Step 6**
:Rename the package name in build.gradle file

[image]

**Step 7**
:Then right-click the old package and delete it with all its data, and delete that directory as well

[image]

**Step 8**
:Then Rebuild your project

[image]

**Step 9**
:Then you will find some errors of old import packagename in your project
**Select the old package name in any file and press** **CTRL + Shift + R** , and enter your new package name in replace box, then press find

[image]

**Step 10**
:Then a popup appears like below and select the All files option from it

[image]

**Step 11**
:Rebuild your project again, bingo your project packagename has been changed :)

Comment: Replace In Path is no longer available tru Shift + R in Android studio 2.3.3, highlight the old path, go to Edit -> Find -> Replace In Path. Also make sure to update your gradle files. Cheers

Comment: Did not get any errors with old package name. So, didn't have to do anything after step 9. Thanks!

Comment: If you did not get any errors, then do not go after step 9

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
> java.io.IOException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

Comment: Instead of Copy, I just Moved and by using this operation instead, I didn't had any erros after rebuild.

Comment: Excellent MS paint writing

Comment: Very nice, but don't forget to change your package name in your google-services.json file manually, If you are using it.

Comment: The most normal way quickly and without errors.

Answer (score 84):

1. Go to your AndroidManifest.xml file.
2. Place your cursor in the package name as shown below. Don't select it, just place it.

   [image]
3. Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> and you will get a popup window as shown below. Select
   **Rename package**.

   [image]
4. Enter your new name and select **Refactor**.
   (Note: since my cursor is on "something", only something is renamed.)

That's it done.

Comment: Thanks working on Android Studio 1.5.1 It changes package automatically  No need to create new package and drag and drop files and delete old package Blah Blah Blah

Comment: @Prince Jayakumar, your **'don't select it just place it'** statement is confusing. just by placing the mouse cursor, shft+f6 won't work. If the caret is somewhere else in the file then you've to click at the package name, then shft+f6 will work

Comment: Easiest way to change package name!

Comment: Complete renaming of package and app id in the fewest steps possible!  Thanks.

Comment: This is the best solution!!

Comment: not working i am pressing shift +f6 its not working

Comment: also u have to change appliation id in gradle file manually. I just did it and it is working, thanks

Comment: This is the right way to deal with the current and latest Android studio application

Answer (score 47):

Right-click on the package at the **Project Panel**.

Choose Refactor -> Rename from the context menu.

Comment: this worked great for me, also had to update the AndroidManifest file too.

Comment: Refactor > Rename only allows me to rename the last part of the package, e.g. the app in com.example.mypackage.app

Comment: I did this way but Now it says class not exist at launch time. How did you renamed it?

Comment: I have used the "Refactor" main menu and click on "Rename".

Comment: @GilliMonsta you can select your app folder in right side panel click settings and un-check Compact Empty Middle Packages

Comment: This works fine but still requires some clean up afterwards. Just do a Build > Clean Project and then a "Find in Path" for the scope of the entire project to find and replace old instances of the previous package name.

Answer (score 42):

**Change the Package Name**

---

To rename your package name, all you have to do is go to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file and put your mouse cursor in front of the part of the package name you want to change.

---

[image]

---

**Right-Click > Refactor > Rename**

---

[image]

---

**In the new window press Rename package**

---

[image]

---

**Change name and press Refactor**

---

[image]

---

**…and press Do Refactor at the bottom.**

---

[image]

---

Your package name usually is in format com.domain.appname; in this example we changed the appname part, but you can do the same steps for the domain too.

Done! You have changed your package name!

Comment: Beautiful answer...quick and precise.. No long steps.

Comment: the best answer here

Comment: Well done BUT it only replaces part of the package like "com" or any other selected!
To replce the Whole string/package name require another solution!

Comment: Followed these steps (not realizing they were out of date). Android Studio tried to build for 2 minutes before failing with the error: "Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported." Well damn Android Studio, you clearly know what I'm *trying* to do! Why not just *do* it, then give a warning popup if you really must

Answer (score 40):

### Android Studio 2023

---

#### Step by Step Implementation

**Step 1:** To rename package name in Android studio open your project in Android mode first as shown in the below image.

[image]

**Step 2:** Now click on the **setting gear icon** and deselect **Compact Middle Packages**.

[image]

**Step 3:** Now the packages folder is broken into parts as shown in the below image.

[image]

**Step 4:** Now right-click on the first package name (com) and **Refactor > Rename**. **A warning message will be displayed but go ahead and click on the Rename current button.**

[image]

**Step 5:** **Rename** the directory name as your requirement and click on the **Refactor** button.

[image]

> **Note:** Go to **Build > Rebuild Project** to display the updated name.

Now you can see your directory name changes from **com -> gfg** as shown in the below image.

[image]

**Step 6:** Do the same for the domain extension and App folder name according to your requirement.

[image]

Now you can see the package name has been changed from **com.example.pulltorefreshwithlistview** to **gfg.geeksforgeeks.listview** as shown in the below image.

[image]

**Step 7:** Now go to the **build.gradle (Module: app)** in Gradle Scripts. Here change the **applicationId** and click on **Sync Now**. And you are successfully renamed your package name.

[image]

---

Source:

- [How to Rename Package Name in Android Studio?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-rename-package-name-in-android-studio/)

Comment: it left empty folders of old package name and didn't change all imports. Try it in real project with multiple modules

Comment: Finally, I have followed this one.

Comment: I also had an applicationId and namespace entry in my module build.gradle that I had to change.

Answer (score 33):

1. Open the file:

   app → manifests → AndroidManifest.xml

   [image]

   Highlight each part in the package name that you want to modify (don't highlight the entire package name) then:

   - Mouse right-click → Refactor → Rename → Rename package
   - type the new name and press (Refactor)

   Do these steps in each part of the package name.

   [image]
2. Open (Gradle Script) >> (build.gradle(Modul:app))

   and update the *applicationId*  to your package name

   [image]
3. Open the menu (build) and choose (Rebuild Project).

Comment: I tried doing this and I hit a snag. I'm trying to change the com.example.android.package to my own domain (which ends .net). I can change 'example' and 'package', but I can't change the 'com'. It also doesn't rename any directories. Any tips?

Comment: @RobertRose, I have a solution for your issue. Are you still working on it?

Comment: I put it aside and just went ahead and left it. It's not production. For future reference, what did you come up with?

Comment: 1st one does not work if i have "xxx.mydomain.com" kind of package)

Comment: beautiful. the second steps are essential and usually looked over in most answers.

Answer (score 20):

Select the package that will be refactored. *Refactor* → *Move* → *"Move xxx to new package"*.

Comment: this is d easy method

Comment: Doesn't work, changed my package from "com.company.oldname" to "com.company.newname.oldname". See? This method doesn't allow to change the last component of the name (and I tried several times).

Answer (score 20):

I have seen the top voted answers but i found is a little bit different to do this, i try to do the most complete tutorial.

From the Android Studio click over the gear icon ( [image: Gears icon] ) and then select the option: `"Compact Empty Middle Packages"`, to see the folders separated in a tree view.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Now select the folder, click right button to open the contextual menu, select **`Refactor`** and then **`Rename`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

You will be advised to refactor the package:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Then a window will show the coincidences inside the proyect, select **`"Do Refactor"`**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**We don´t have to change manually the AndroidManifest.xml or build.gradle files, Refactoring the package will do the job!.**

Answer (score 19):

IntelliJ IDEA has an option called "Compact Empty Middle Packages". Select the option icon of the *Project* tab and de/activate this.

See: *[How can I change top level package name in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764277/how-can-i-change-top-level-package-name-in-intellij)*

Comment: This was useful.  After 'Deactivating' this feature things were much clearer and I could delete packages that were empty

Comment: @ChrisNevill and how did u delete those empty packages please?

Comment: I think I just selected them and pressed delete.  I can't reproduce the issue at the moment so can't remember it exactly.

Comment: I agree, this was REALLY useful. Should be included in all the sub-standard answers I've seen regarding this topic.

Answer (score 14):

I also had a hard time changing the package name of a project. Especially big projects. It has so much to do, but those jobs are really boring. I've been developing a plugin on IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio. It will help you to automatically change the package name automatically. It's called Android Package Renamer

### Installation

- Using IDE built-in plugin system:

  <kbd>Settings/Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Plugins</kbd> > <kbd>Marketplace</kbd> > <kbd>Search for "Android Package Renamer"</kbd> >
  <kbd>Install Plugin</kbd>
- Manually:

  Download the [latest release](https://github.com/nguyenphuc22/Android-Package-Renamer/releases/latest) and install it manually using
  <kbd>Settings/Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Plugins</kbd> > <kbd>⚙️</kbd> > <kbd>Install plugin from disk...</kbd>

### Usage

1. **Open** Your Project.
2. Click -> **File** -> **Rename Package**
3. **Input the Package** you want to change.
4. Click **Ok**.
5. **Sync Project with Gradle Files** or **Invalidate Caches**

### This plugin can rename packages (it can do more):

- com.android.example -> org.nickseven.product
- com.android.example -> org.nickseven
- com.android.example -> org.nickseven.product.native
- com.android.etc.nick.d -> org.android.otd.nick.d

If this plugin helps you or there is an error, contact me through the following [GitHub](https://github.com/nguyenphuc22/Android-Package-Renamer)

Comment: The plugin worked like magic:)

Comment: didn't work for multi module projects, also lefts empty folders, basically renamed app module only, and partially the second module, all others modules remained unchanged

Comment: @user924 I think you are right, you can create an issue on my github, I will support your case in the next version

Comment: Much love brother, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

**Quick and easy way in 3 steps:**

1- open `MainActivity` or any other java or Kotlin file.

At the top there is the package declaration such as:

> package com.`example`.myapp;

select the package portion that you want to change and press **Shift+F6**. I personally want to change the `example`.

In the warning dialog, select **Rename package** and then insert the desired package name.

2- Open `AndroidManifest.xml` and inside `<manifest>` tag change the `package` to the desired package name.

3- open `build.gradle(Module: app)` and change the `applicationId` to the desired package  name.

Comment: Thank you. It is quite simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 11):

If your package name is more than two dot separated, say `com.hello.world` and moreover, you did not put anything in `com/` and `com/hello/`. All of your classes are putting into `com/hello/world/`, you might DO the following steps to refactoring your package name(s) in Android Studio or IntelliJ:

- **[FIRST]** Add something under your directories(`com/`, `com/hello/`). You can
  achieve this by first add two files to package com.hello.world, say

> ```
>    com.hello.world.PackageInfo1.java
>    com.hello.world.PackageInfo2.java
> ```

then refactor them by moving them to com and com.hello respectively.
   You will see com and com.hello sitting there at the Project(`Alt+1`
   or `Command+1` for shortcut) and rename directories refactoring is
   waiting there as you expected.

- Refactor to rename one or more of these directories to reach your aim. The only thing you should notice here is you must choose the directories rather than Packages when a dialog ask you.
- If you've got lots of classes in your project, it will take you a while to wait for its auto-scan-and-rename.
- Besides, you need to rename the package name inside the AndroidManifest.xml manually, I guess, such that other names in this file can benefit the prefix.
- **[ALSO]**, it might need you to replace all `com.hello.world.R` to the new `XXX.XXX.XXX.R`(`Command+Shift+R` for short)
- Rebuild and run your project to see whether it work. And use "Find in Path" to find other  non-touch names you'd like to rename.
- Enjoy it.

Answer (score 9):

Be sure to go to [Sheharyar's great Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio/29092698#29092698). There are so many answers and comments that follow it that it would be easy to get confused and give up, but *don't*. That answer *works*.

In short, you do *three things*:

(1) Deselect `Compact Empty Middle Packages`.

(2) `Refactor` then `Rename` each old directory node by choosing `Change Package` (*not* `Change Directory`) to match the new package name. (Be sure to do a preview of changes.)

(3) Edit the `build.gradle` file and make `APPLICATION_ID` match the new package name.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this truly is missing something, since my Answer is a synopsis of Sheharyar's answer THAT GOT 332 UPVOTES and all I did was simpllify it since it looks so involved (it isn't). The nerve of some shortsighted, trigger-happy people. Would LOVE to see reason for downvote. Have no doubt I won't see it.

Comment: OK. As of 3.5 years later, I can maybe see why the downvotes might have been cast since it might not have been completely clear as it WAS (but cut some slack!), but it sure is now, thanks to @Peter Mortensen's two-day-old edit and mine just now.

Answer (score 8):

The common mistake that one can make is one cannot rename the package structure i.e. it is not possible to change *com.name.android* to *com.Renamed.android* when one tries to modify at the *com.name.android* level.

In order to have the same desired change go one level up i.e *com.name* and here when you refactor change it to *Renamed*. This will work always.

Answer (score 8):

1. Select the package name in the Java folder.
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>
3. Change the package name and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Your package name will be changed from all the Java files and the manifest file. You have to manually change the package name from `build.gradle`.

Comment: If Shift+F6 is not working for you, then you can try Alt+Shift+R to refactor the package. Rest of the procedure is the same

Answer (score 8):

I've found a way easier solution to this problem which also changed the generated imports like `com.test.testpackagechange.R` and only takes about a minute.

Your first step is to open Android Studio and open the replace all window (Mac: cmd + shift + R, Windows I assume: ctrl + shift + R). Type in your old package name and in the one below your new package name. Click Find. This may take a while because it is also looking through the generated items. If it has over 1000 hits, just click continue.

[image]

After you've done that push Replace All to replace your old package name with your new one.

[image]

Now close Android Studio and go to Finder on Mac or Windows Explorer on Windows. Change the name of the folders to your new package name, like this:

[image]

Now open Android Studio again. Gradle will sync and your package name should be changed to the new one.

I've found this to be the easiest one and the one that covers all areas like generated files.

Answer (score 7):

Packages serve two purposes. One is to uniquely identify your app in the Google Play Store. The other is to name the package for the **`R.java class`** which is generated when you build your project. You can think of the first purpose as the external package and the second as the internal package. Assuming you want to change the external package so you can identify in the Play store, there's a convenient way to do this.

**In Android Studio,**

```
 choose File -> Project Structure -> Choose your app's module -> Click on the 
 Flavors tab -> change the Application id.
```

Now, when you build your project, 
     your APK and manifest will use this new package name.

Answer (score 7):

I tried the two top-voted solutions but found some issues even though both work to some extent.

- List item: The new package-drag-drop method leaves some unchanged and creates some undesired effects
- List item: The rename package only changes the last part of the package name

After some experiments, I found the following method works well for me.

If you just need to change the last part of the package name, use the method outlined by GreyBeardedGeek, namely

Right-click on the package in the Project pane. Choose Refactor -> Rename from the context menu

If you need to change the whole package name, do the following.

Right-click on the package in the Project pane. Choose Refactor -> Move from the context menu

This will create a new package folder (when necessary) but will keep the last part of your package name as before.  If you need to change the last part, do the rename accordingly.

Note also that you may need to modify package names in e.g. build.gradle, manifest, and/or any xml resource files, or even in your code if hardcoded.  After all that, do Sync/Clean/Rebuild project as necessary.

Answer (score 7):

I found another way that works or an extra step to some of the answers here especially if you want to change the domain as well. It works in Android Studio 1.4. This is what I did:

1. Open Manifest.xml and change the package name to what you want.
2. Open your app `build.gradle` file and change the Application Id in defaultConfig to the same name as in manifest and rebuild the project.
3. If still an issue, open a file under the package name, go to the package breadcrumbs (i.e. package declaration at head of file) and set your cursor to the domain you want to change and hit "Shift + F6", it would come out with a dialog with multiple use warnings, click on "Rename packages" and then click on "Do Refactor" it should rename everything including the R.Java files.

So for example if you want to rename "com.example.app" to "com.YourDomain.app", open a file under the package to be renamed, in the package breadcrumbs, set your cursor to "example" part of the domain and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> and rename package to "YourDomain".

Answer (score 6):

- The first part consists of creating a new package under the `java` folder and selecting then dragging all your source files from the `old package` to this `new package`. After that, you need to `rename the package name in android` manifest` to the name of the new package.
- In step 2, here is what you need to do. You need to change the old package name in `applicationId` under the module `build.gradle` in your android studio in addition to changing the package name in the `manifest`. So in summary, click on `build.gradle` which is below the "AndroidManifest.xml" and modify the value of `applicationId` to your new package name.
- Then, at the very top, under `build`. `clean` your project, then `rebuild`. It should be fine from here.

Answer (score 6):

The best way is to write the new package name and drag from the older package name.

The second way, if you click *Refactor* then move option then rename the package name, it will rename the package name and then rebuild.

In Build.gradle you have to do manually, if you Refactor then it will not rename in Build.gradle.

Answer (score 6):

Right click on package -> refactor and change the name.

You can also change it in the manifest. Sometimes if you change the package name, but after creating the .apk file it shows a different package name. At that time check "applicationId" in the *build.gradle* file.

Answer (score 6):

**Updated answer: May 2015**

OK I have been struggling with cloning & renaming projects in Android Studio, but finally I achieved it. Here are the steps to follow:

1. Copy the project folder, rename it & open it with Android Studio
2. Rename module directory from explorer
3. Rename projectName.iml and content
4. Rename idea/.name content
5. In your Project pane, click on the little gear icon -> uncheck "Compact Empty Middle Package"
6. Refactor src directories for new package name (rename package, "not rename directory")
7. In build.gradle rename application id
8. settings.gradle rename module

That's it...

Answer (score 6):

I recommend to use [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) (or [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B)). Replace com.one.lastname -> com.two.newname and com/one/lastname -> com/two/newname in ...\Projects[MyProject]. And don't forget to rename ...\Projects\MyProject\app\src\main\java\com\one\lastname, ...\Projects\MyProject\app\src\test\java\com\one\lastname and ...\Projects\MyProject\app\src\androidTest\java\com\one\lastname!

That's all:)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

How to rename `com.example.app` to `com.android.app`:

1. in package `com.example.app` select example
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>
3. choose `rename package`
4. rename example to android
5. confirm `do refactor`

Answer (score 5):

There are many answers given, but still, I am giving my attempt.

Step 1 :
As Show in the fig above select the Setting Option...
[image]

Step 2:
Select Compact Middle Packages option...
[image]

Step 3:
Now Expand the package as shown
[image]

Step 4:
After expanding it will look something like
[image]

Step 5:
Select any on the subpackage (in or example or googledevsmsverify) and click Shift+f6 button...
[image]

I selected middle package **example** so it will display as above fig
simple rename the package and click on the refactor button

[image]

Step 6:
you will see the following screen after clicking Refactor button, click on the DO Refactor, and wait until build the gradle...
[image]

Step 7:
Goto build.gradle(Mobile:app) and change the  package name of applicationID as shown
[image]

Step 8:
Just check the package in the manifest.xml file...

[image]

All Done the package is change...@Ambilpura

Answer (score 5):

THERE ARE TWO THINGS - PACKAGE NAME and APPLICATION ID.

The easiest and most satisfying way for me is this,

[image]

Can you see the highlighting line "vijayjangid", it was "example" before.
All I did was renamed example using refractor and the android studio did all the work.

FIRST PART DONE.

Now rename the application id in defaultConfig brackets to the same as the name you renamed the example folder. Make sure you rename the package name and id in cloud services like firebase, Aws, realm, etc.

That's it you are done, the most upvoted answer is old, we need to update the answers.

Answer (score 3):

This I believe what you are looking for is Refactor > Move. You can also press F6.

You will get two popups. Make sure you select rename package on both. After that you will get a pop up to place the new package name.

Please note that if your package name is, for example, com.example.android.projectname then this will let you change com.example.android to something else.

One more thing, this will update the applicationId in your build.gradle as well. Just make sure that the checkboxes for "search in comments and strings" and "search for text occurrences" are both checked for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

1. Select option [image]
2. Uncheck the Compact Empty Middle Packages option.
3. Select which directory you want to change(I have selected 'crl' shown in step 6).
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>
5. Rename Package
6. Renaming directory crl to crl1
   [image]
7. Finally click on Do Refactor button marked in image below
   [image]
8. After Changes done
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> has always worked for me.
Simply `replace all` and choose `All Files`.

Comment: this wont update directories and it will not find any of your classes

Answer (score 3):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Replace the old package with the new one.
3. Right click on the package name.
4. `Refactor` > `Rename` and rename to the new one

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following steps:

1. Click on the setting gear icon and deselect Compact Empty Middle Package
2. Now we can see each package folder is broken into parts
3. Now right click on the first package folder >>> refactor >>> rename
4. Now a warning will be displayed but you go ahead and click Rename
   Package
5. After that enter your domain name for the package name
6. Click on ‘Do Refactor’
7. Now it has changed the package domain name of the App. Now Change the
   domain extension and App folder name according to your requirement
8. Now open build.gradle (Module: app) in Gradle Scripts. Here change the application id and click Sync Now.

*******Finally it’s done ******

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[3 Methods to change package name in Android Studio](https://androidride.com/how-to-change-rename-android-app-package-name-android-studio/)

I think this is a new one. I tried it and it's working. If the above doesn't work for you. Try this. On the site I mentioned above, there are 2 other methods too with image tutorials. I also checked.

First I am going to talk about changing the Package name. In this example, We will change the package name “com.androidride.myapplication” to “info.xyz.yourapplication”.

1. Right click on the package name you want to change and select **Refactor - > Move**.
2. A new dialog appears, Choose **Move package “com.androidride.myapplication” to another package** and click on **Ok**.
3. A warning dialog appears, click on **yes**.
4. Enter new package name in the new dialog. But only “info.xyz” leave yourapplication.
5. Now you will see a warning dialog says Package info.xyz does not exist. Do you want to create it? click on **yes**.
6. Click on “**Do Refactor”**. Now your package name changed to **info.xyz.myapplication**.
7. Right click on **info.xyz.myapplication** and **Refactor -> Rename**.
8. Click on **Rename package**.
9. Rename dialog: change **myapplication** to **yourapplication**.
10. Click on **Do refactor**.
11. Delete old package name directories and change application id in **build.gradle**, change it into **info.xyz.yourapplication**.
12. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

The question asked:

> Is there an automatic refactoring included?

> I want to make bulk refactoring, but I don't know how. I worked two years with Eclipse and in Eclipse it's a one-click operation.

Well, *almost* one-click with automatic refactoring, but just one small step first, i.e., just the small step to create the new package. Here is the full solution below.

You can rename a package by creating a new package (including the required folder path) and then drag-and-drop over from the old package (and let Android Studio take care of the refactoring of the various references from the old package to the new), as follows:

1. Right click on `java` under `app`. [image: Right click on java under app]
2. Select `New` and `Package` [image]
3. Select the location for the new package as ../app/src/main/java [image]
4. Enter the full name of the new package [image]
5. The new package will be created. Now, drag-and-drop over from the old package to the new. Preview the refactoring if you'd like to check that Android Studio is doing it properly. If it all looks good, proceed with the refactoring.

NB: since application ID and package name are decoupled these days, note that the above is only for renaming the package name. For changing the application ID, you can do that in your `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to project path > where you located Java files and package
- Create new folders, for example com → super_package → activities
- Android Studio will refresh project structure
- Move all Java files to new folders
- Remove old folders
- Menu *Edit* → *Find* → Replace in path:
- Change old package name to new
- Change also in manifest and build gradle

Done!

Answer (score 2):

Go to AndroidManifest.xml
There you will find the package as the attribute of the manifest tag.
Just select the part you want to change,
right-click-> refactor -> rename

Maybe earlier it was hard, but as of today, it is not anymore.

You might also want to change the app id in

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 
}
```

Short & Sweet

Comment: The question everyone has is: Do we still have to de-select `Compact Empty Middle Packages` and change each (dir) name at the time. For example, if you want to change your package name from `com.test.app` to `in.myapp.test`?

Answer (score 2):

> Right Click on the Package name -> Refractor ->Rename -> enter the name of the package ->Click “Refractor”.
>   Do not edit any of the build files except “build.gradle” under the “app” folder.

From [Renaming android studio project - Vishnu Sivan](http://mobileandroidappdevelopment.blogspot.in/2015/11/how-to-rename-android-studio-project.html)

Answer (score 1):

That works very well for me, even for changing the occurrences, in all the modules concerned, for the folders names I want to modify in the package but, for me, it works fine *only* if I follow exactly the following steps :

- A - If you want to change the name of the root folder (in other words the folder's name who is normaly used in the package to contain the principal activity), you can do it *before* or *after* the following steps (B to C) by exiting from "Android Studio" and rename manually this root folder. Click after on "Import project..." and then on the new name of your project (this import process will automatically readjust the 'Gradle' files with the project files.)
- B - *before* the following C step, don't forget to modify manually the folder's names you want to change in the package by changing them in the 3 following files: 'AndroidManifest.xml', 'MainActivity.java' (or the name you eventually choose for your first activity) and the 'build.gradle (Module: app)' file.
- C - Follow the steps 1 to 6 described above ("In your Project pane, click on the little gear icon...") -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/2001610
- D - Only if you want to change the name of the root folder now, you can follow the 'A' process, as described above.

Answer (score 1):

After you follow one of these techniques to get your package renamed, you might start seeing errors.

If / when your R.java is not getting generated properly, you'll get a lot of errors in your project saying `error: cannot find symbol class R` and also `error: package R does not exist`.

Remember to check your Application manifest xml. The manifest package name **must match** the actual package name. It seems the R.java is generated from the Application Manifest and can cause these errors if there's a mismatch.

Remember to check the `package` attribute matches in your `<manifest package="com.yourcompany.coolapp">`

Answer (score 1):

To rename the package name in Android studio, Click on the setting icon in the project section and untick the **Compact empty Middle Packages**, after that the package will split into multiple folder names, then right-click on the folder you need to change the name, click on **refactor**-> **Rename**-> **Type the name you want to change in** -> **Refactor** -> **Refactor Directory**, then import R.java file in the whole project. Working for me.

Answer (score 1):

- First, you need to go to the settings icon which is Appear in left. Click on that dropdown and uncheck Compact Empty Middle Packages

Go to Your AndroidManifest.xml

1. Select All of your Package and then Right click there
2. Refactor and then rename that how you want.
3. and then go to your build.gradle and then change Applicationid with packagename that what you have in Android Manifest.

**It is worked For Me**

Answer (score 1):

I needed to run File->Invalidate Caches/Restart... to remove remnants of the original package

Answer (score 0):

If your package starts with `mypackageold.something.test` then you can't change to `mypackagenew.somethingnew.testnew`.

In this case, if I follow above accepted answer steps result will be `mypackageold.somethingnew.testnew`.

Only if your package starts with `com....` to New package, above accepted answer will work.

So if you want to change the package from Root Level

1. Change the Required package name inside manifest,
2. Remove the old package and Crate New Package under Android tab,
3. Drag all the Files from old Package to New Package,
4. Inside the Manifest also change the package name for those files,
5. Clean Project,
6. Open `build.gradle` and update `applicationId`.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a good keyboard shortcut key just click `n` select the `Class / Package` which you want to rename and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>  **+ two times** <kbd>R</kbd>  **or** <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>F6</kbd>

**which reflect :->** `Refactor` menu and `Rename` function in Android Studio. After rename the existing package it shows in bottom side where the effect of this `reflection / rename` if you click on `Refector` button it will change the `Class name / Package name` where is used in whole Project.

Answer (score 0):

for example if you want change package from com.example.a to com.example.b

1)change project style folder from android to package (in project side)

2)right click top of folder and click replace in path

3)select in project button

4)in first input write com.example.a

5)in second input write com.example.b

6)when you see warning select replace all to replace value

after finish replace you can see your package name is com.example.b

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.
Here's a python script to change the package name directly on the source files.

```
"""
Notes:
1 - This script it for python3
2 - Create a backup first
3 - Place on the root folder of the android project you want to change
4 - run `python change_android_studio_pkg_name.py`
5 - Type the old package name
6 - Type the new package name
7 - Clean and Rebuild on Android Studio
8 - SRC folder names won't be changed but app will work
"""

import os, glob, traceback
from pathlib import Path

def rwf(fp, mode="r", data="" ):
    if mode == "r":
        with open(fp, "r", encoding='utf8') as f:
            return(f.read())
    elif mode == "w":
        with open(fp, "w", encoding='utf8') as f:
            f.write(data)

old_pkg = input("Old PKG\n").strip()
new_pkg = input("New PKG\n").strip()

if not old_pkg or not new_pkg:
    exit("Args Missing")

dirname, filename = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))
file_types = ['xml', 'txt', 'json', 'gradle', 'java']
_fs =  glob.iglob(f"{dirname}/**", recursive=True)
for file_path in _fs:
    ext = Path(file_path).suffix.replace(".", "").lower()
    if os.path.isfile(file_path) and ext in file_types:
        try:
            content = rwf(file_path)
            new_content = content.replace(old_pkg, new_pkg)
            rwf(file_path, "w", new_content)
        except:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
            pass
```

[python3 gist](https://gist.github.com/x011/040e0a6b83b7c3aa311024bbf5cc21cc)

Answer (score 0):

For me , i just changed the directory name instead of package name of the **library module** and clicked Do refactor at the bottom (example: from com.reg.register -> com.reg1.register).

After that make sure you updated the new directory name in build gradle file and manifest file.

Rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `package` in the `java` directory and move your project into that package. Like your current project id is `com.testapp.user` and you want to change it `xyz.testapp.user`. Then create a package in `src/java` directory named xyz and move your child package `testapp.user` into xyz. It works for me. Finally, update build.gradle and `manifest` project id.

Answer (score 0):

it will work fine for me

```
Change Following.
```

**Step 1:** Make sure ApplicationId And PackageName will Same.
example :

```
  android {
  defaultConfig {
                     applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
                 }
       }
 and package name the same. package="com.example.myapplication"
```

**Step 2**
delete iml file in my case :

```
  Go To Project> >C:\Users\ashif\Documents\MyApplication  .iml file // delete 
if you forget Project Path Then Go To android Studio Right Click on app and go to  Show in Explorer you get your Project and remove .iml file
```

**Step 3**
Close Project

**Step 4**
Now Copy Your old Project and Paste Any other Root or copy Project Folder and paste Any
other Dir.

```
 Example C:\Users\ashif\Documents/MyApplication
```

**Step 5**

```
Now open Android Studio and open Existing Project 
C:\Users\ashif\Documents/MyApplication
```

Try it will work

Answer (score 0):

*If* your only reason for renaming is to avoid collision with another build (or a system app) with the same package name, then you can instead rename **ONLY** the `applicationId` in your app's **`build.gradle`** file.

*Example*: Given that you already have an app installed with the id `com.android.phone` (which you want to keep) change your `app/build.gradle` to:

```groovy
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.phone.mymod"

}
```

I.e. if you already have an app with the package name `com.android.phone` and don't want/cannot uninstall it (for example because it's a system app and the device is not rooted) then the change above is *all* that is needed in order to have your app installed side-by-side with the original app. On the device the `applicationId` is what will be used and not the actual package name. Also your app data will be stored under `/data/data/com.android.phone.mymod` rather than `/data/data/com.android.phone`.

> <sup>NB. In certain cases you might also need to rename the names of providers and authorities in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.</sup>

Reference:

- https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id

> When you create a new project in Android Studio, the `applicationId` exactly matches the Java-style package name you chose during setup. However, the application ID and package name are independent of each other beyond this point. You can change your code's package name (your code namespace) and it will not affect the application ID, and vice versa (though, again, you should not change your application ID once you publish your app). However, changing the package name has other consequences you should be aware of, so see the section about how to [change the package name](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id#change_the_package_name).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anyone point this out, that is why I am writing this answer. I would have added this answer as a comment because it really doesn't deserve to be an answer but I don't have enough reputation points on Stackoverflow to leave a comment.

I was looking to change my package name from **com.param.myapp** to **com.pvs.myapp**. I followed every solution on the internet but forgot to change the `namespace 'com.param.myapp'` to the `namespace 'com.pvs.myapp'` in build.gradle(:app) in android block. I am not sure if namespace line needed to exist but it was giving me errors. Android Studio was generating classes under the old package name.

Just remember to check it!

Answer (score 0):

If your use case fits the description of a 'variant' or a 'mod' of the original app then you can avoid the hassle of renaming your packages, and can leave alone the `namespace` *and* the `applicationId`, and instead define the **`applicationIdSuffix`** in your `build.gradle`, e.g.:

```bash
defaultConfig {
    namespace "com.original.app"
    applicationId "com.original.app"
    versionCode 42
    versionName "0.42"
    applicationIdSuffix '.insidersBuild'
    ################### ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

*Keep in mind*: If you don’t explicitly define the `applicationId` in your `build.gradle`'s `defaultConfig`, then the value is inferred from the package attribute in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

<sub>*See also:*</sub>

- https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants#groovy + see about [*flavors*](https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants#product-flavors) right below

Answer (score -2):

It is very easy to do. Just follow two steps:

1. Right click on root folder and click on open module settings.
2. After this go to flavors tab and change application id as you wish.

For those who are thinking that this will only change the application id in build.gradle file:

It is written by Google that

> The final package that is used in your built .apk's manifest, and is the package your app is known as on your device and in the Google Play store, is the "application id".

and

> The package that is used in your source code to refer to your R class, and to resolve any relative activity/service registrations, continues to be called the "package".

You can read more on http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename