# IntelliJ Java resources directory/packages question

Tags: java, intellij-idea, directory, package

this is probably a big stupid question on my part but it's been a problem for me. So I'm trying to add different directories to my java resources folder in IntelliJ, but it keeps adding a "example.example" on top of my directory. If I don't add anything to the previous directory, it'll only let me create a file in that newest directory. it won't let me make a new file in the previous directory and I would like to know if I can add packages to resources as well. I saw other people use packages in the resources folder and I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong. I would really appreciate some advice and how the whole directory works, because I'm completely stumped on how the resources and directories work, I really can't find anything for it. Thank you, I'm fairly new and confused.[example of the directory problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lYVD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`example.example` must be your package name. All Java files in IntelliJ use packaging, so your directory created has to be example.example.yourdirectory. Packaging is a way of storing files in an organized way. The Java package name is the same as the folder names that they are stored in. Typically, your package name is your website in reverse order like com.example.app, so your folders would be com\example\app. For more information on packages, see [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).

If you want to know how to change your package name, try reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16764347/8804293).